# Get return value from php threads

Tags: php, pthreads

This is the sample code, I'm working on

```
class workerThread extends Thread {
  public function __construct($i){
     $this->i=$i;
}

public function run(){
  while(true){
   echo $this->i;
   sleep(1);
  }
}
}

for($i=0;$i<50;$i++){
$workers[$i]=new workerThread($i);
$workers[$i]->start();
}
```

What is the appropriate way to get return value from run() or should create another function for callback?

Comment: To return from function `run()` use `return` keyword.

Comment: FWIW, ”What is best way to...” is fairly subjective here, since it depends of the situation you have there.

Comment: @Smar I agree with you and thanks for edit

Comment: @Justinas that won't function, because for loop would stop before getting return value

Answer (score 1):

well first you have to wait for all threads to finish.

so after your initial loop you should do one more loop waiting for each worker to finish. there is `thread->join` function that syncs your main thread with the sub-thread. causing to halt the execution and wait until the sub thread finishes. so if you call `if($worker->join()) {...}` you can be sure, that the worker is done working :)

http://php.net/manual/de/thread.join.php

second, a thread does not return a value. instead create a variable in your class, for example `result` and fill it with data during the run of a thread. collect at the end (after `join`) the `$worker->result`

third, your current threads even cannot report any result, as they run for ever. From the question I dont understand, if you want them to run for ever? Because if you do there are more complicated steps involved to get the results continuously.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time in this, for your third point, yes that's true, it was just a sample of thread I copied from manual, I have big written class in threads so could not post that. Also could you please explain join.

Comment: yeah, see my update. it just waits for your worker thread to finish. so you can create 50 workers, and after you created them, you wait for each one of them (again in a loop and $worker->join()).

Comment: Technically speaking if I use join with 50 threads.  $worker->join() would execute another thread after completion of previous thread. So this kills threads concept. I think if two workers are called, one proxy worker and another functional worker. The proxy worker should be able to join and work as thread. Finally this will make the code complex, when I could simply create another callback function instead of making more threads. Correct me if I'm wrong, kindly suggest me :)